# Change position of local variable to lowest address in stack

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, assembly, 32-bit

I have written simple code in order to study assembler.

Task im trying to do is in assembler part: mycode.s
Im curious, how would i be able to manually change position of my local variable **int var** ( it is located on stack, because its local)  to lowest possible location(address) in stack...

Im using following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int c = 0;

int main()
{
    int var = 0;
    if( var == c)
    {
        printf("here");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i assemble my code with **gcc -m32 -S mycode.c**
i get:

```
    .file   "mycode.c"
    .globl  c
    .bss
    .align 4
    .type   c, @object
    .size   c, 4
c:
    .zero   4
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
   .string  "here"
   .text
   .globl   main
   .type    main, @function
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $20, %esp
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
    movl    c, %eax
    cmpl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    jne .L2
    subl    $12, %esp
    pushl   $.LC0
    call    printf
    addl    $16, %esp
.L2:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    -4(%ebp), %ecx
    leave
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

What instructions can i use to check the current stack addresses and find the lowest possible address (for example: 0x003 < 0x004).. Thanks

Comment: If you want to change the working result of a compiler into different code which has the local variable on a different lcation (it is what I understand) then pleae show the compiler output AND your attempt to change it. Also please state what you mean by "lowest position on stack". The lowest address in all stack space or the lowest address within the frame of this function?

Comment: you can find addresses of all local variables in C by storing `&local_variable` into some array and sorting them.. but if that array is local variable... but you can't decide where the local variable will land in the C source, as the C language has no ways to define that (and the local variable will often not live in stack at all, but only in register, for better performance). You can afterwards modify the .s file produced by compiler, to rearrange local variables positions, but that will be very cumbersome and error prone, so you may try as an exercise once to do that, but makes little sense.

Comment: As the `var` is the only local variable, it's already on lowest position. Do you have problem with the `esp = ebp-24` and the `var` being located at `ebp-12` only? Then just overwrite those `-12` to `-24`, the code looks like it doesn't use that area for anything (`ebp-24 ... ebp-21` area), but verify in debugger there's nothing important while running it, and that I did correctly guess it's `ebp-24` - the bottom of stack after function prologue... Your compiler is producing lot of noise of useless code, so if you can't change the C source, nor use -O2, understand the clutter perfectly first.

Comment: the assignment i have to do is to modify the .s file. As i understood, by using ** gcc  -g -o mycode mycode.s** and then **gdb mycode**... Now i could use commands such as **b main** (breakpoint at label main) , **r** (run), then to check adress of for example EIP (instr pointer): **i r eip** ... This way i can find where my local variable is stored, but im not sure how to proceed to change its position ( which lowest address in stack is available to place my variable into)

Comment: In 32 bit code the `esp` points to the current "top of the stack", but it grows downwards, i.e. `push %eax` will first subtract 4 from `esp` to reserve new 32 bit space, then it will store the value of `eax` into that memory. So after instruction `subl    $20, %esp` it looks the compiler is done with the prologue stuff, and starts to work on actual C code, you can check value in `esp` and `ebp` there, and view the memory area there, actually you should watch that memory probably whole time while stepping over `main` code. I don't like the AT&T syntax, so I did just a quick look: esp=ebp-24 ?

Comment: The `esp` is then current stack pointer (any `push/pop/call/ret` instruction will use that value as starting point for its functionality), `ebp` is "stack-frame" pointer, which is used for accessing local variables and similar, because it doesn't modify with `push/pop/...`, so the `var` will be always at `ebp-12` (as long as `ebp` doesn't get modified), while the `esp+12` addressing would be correct at the beginning, but may change to other offset if the code gets more complex and will need to push something other on stack.

Comment: Mind you, this is all very fragile stuff being not followed by compiler when you start to use optimizations, or other compile time options, so it's very weird why you are given such tasks, instead of explaining you some assembly/computer basics, you are being trained in information which is not usable in real world project (as optimized code often doesn't even set the stack frame into `ebp`, either avoiding stack usage completely, or using the `esp` with offsets adjusted by the current stack position, as it's not that hard for compiler to track current relative position of `esp` to `var`).

Comment: And teaching you first some basics about how memory works, and what you can see in debugger, and such, would make you to understand this prologue code and stack usage better, so in the end it would be win win, from your question it looks like you are a bit lacking in the basics, and already trying to learn how stack frame in unoptimized C code works, are you trying to learn assembly programming, or is this part of some exploit/security class, and you will not delve into assembly much? If you are learning assembly, stop doing this sh*t and get some tutorial for basics first.

Comment: This is description for current part of my task: " Once you understand the stack, you realize that typically in the stack frame there are also "other places" for local variables. Change the assembler code from Experiment 1.2: Set the local variable to the smallest possible address in the stack frame. Explanation for small: 3 is less than 5

Comment: yes im learning assembly, but i dont think it will go much deeper than this, next exercises are focused on internet connections, understanding routers, mac, ip etc.

Comment: As I wrote above, from a quick look I guess the area `ebp-24..ebp-13` is "free", being "reserved" by compiler as stack alignment and maybe for some "ghost" local variables which got optimized out even with `-g` (the `main` function is often displaying some quirk behaviour in non-optimized builds, often related to implicit `return 0`, but your compiler may have more on mind). The exercise looks to be focused on stack understanding, so do that... breakpoint on `main`, and keep checking `ebp` vs `esp` and content of `esp` memory area, to see if `var` is at `ebp-12` and if `ebp-24..-13` is free.

Comment: thanks so much this was helpful, im playing with debuger right now. just one question: about ebp -24... is this because :  `andl    $-16, %esp `     `pushl   %ebp ` AND 
 `movl    %esp, %ebp`   this seems to add up to -24 if im not weong

Comment: the `and` will just align `esp` to be on 16B boundary (it may decrease `esp` by anything between 0 to 15, or to put it other way, it clears the low 4 bits of `esp`), then old `ebp` is stored into aligned stack, then current top of stack is copied as stack-frame pointer into `ebp`, so the frame of your `main` basically starts there, after this sequence, that was prologue to prologue, aligning stack and preparing it for usage for `main`. THEN the `ecx` is pushed onto stack too (value preservation), and `20` is subtracted from `esp`, creating the "ebp-24" state of `esp`+reserving space for locals

Comment: @Ped7g i have checked memory area **from**  `ebp-12`(here is my local variable stored) **to** `ebp -24` ( ebp -24 = esp) .  `ebp-14` = `0x0000ffff` and then `ebp-15` = `0x00ffffd0` . FROM location `ebp-15` to `ebp-24` all locations seem to have some values ( ex: ebp-16 = 0xffffd00c, and so on)... I think i could place , my variable to **ebp-14**...

Comment: the computer memory has always SOME values (if you receive zeroed area of memory from OS, like upon memory allocation, it's work done by the OS or memory allocator, the memory chip itself can't tell when it is supposed to "clear" (as long as powered)). The question is, were they stored there by the code running (after the `subl $20, %esp` instruction) and are they used later before end of the function (before "releasing" the memory by restoring `esp` back to the area where `ebp` points or above), or are they just random junk in the memory from before, and the code doesn't use that area.

Comment: you can try upon entering `main` to set the values under initial `esp` to some simple pattern, like 0xAAAAAAAA to esp-40 to esp-4, to see, which bytes were overwritten/used by the function code and when (I don't know if gdb has some nice memory view at hand, maybe you will have to print all those values from time to time, I use different debugger).

Comment: oh.. btw, depending on how the debugger implements breakpoints and single-step, the advice above to put the marker value in the stack area may be useless, as the debugger itself may overwrite values under stack with it's own push instructions, when it is taking control after single step. But after `subl $20, %esp` the `main` code has actually control over this newly reserved area `esp+0 ... esp+19`, so you can also put those marker values there after the `sub` (just make sure you don't overwrite the old value of `ecx` stored by `push` before the `sub`, which is at area `esp+20..esp+23` ATM).